# develop a teams app without a work/school account

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Im trying to create a teams extension/app without using my school or working email since i would need to ask my administrator. I just want to do some testing without deploying the app.

Thanks

I tried to sign in to a basic account, school account but sideloading isn't activated and I need to ask the administrator for such a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft provides free 365 developer accounts for exactly this type of need - please see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program

Comment: thanks i successfully created one :)

Comment: great, glad to help. Please Mark as Answer so others with a similar question can get benefit. Good luck with your project!